# New state with Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to switch state with a collision. So when the player hits another sprite it should switch state, but it doesn't..

First I'm declaring the player and the enterDoor sprites under `create:`:

```
playerSprite = this.game.add.sprite(50, 1700, 'player-front');
    player = new Player(playerSprite);
    this.game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

enterDoor = this.game.add.sprite(332, 830, 'player-back');
    playerDoor = new Player(enterDoor);
    this.game.physics.enable(playerDoor, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
```

Then I'm trying to make the overlap under `update:` :

```
this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, playerDoor, this.enterHouse, null, this);
```

And enterHouse is another function:

```
enterHouse: function() {
  this.state.start('Menu');  
}
```

What am I doin' wrong?

Comment: What version of Phaser, and are you getting any messages in the browser console?

Comment: The newest version, and no. It's just that nothing happens

Comment: I believe you should define your collision handler as:
`enterHouse: function(obj1, obj2) { // instructions }` because callback function will be called with two overlapping objects in order which you specified them in overlap.

Answer (score 0):

So with the code above I wasn't able to get the `overlap` to trigger at all. After disabling [`moves`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.7/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#moves) on the player sprite's `body` the `overlap` was triggered.

```
player.body.moves = false;
```

Your `enterHouse` function doesn't need to accept the two sprites, and can be left as-is.

What I don't know is why this is necessary.