# Collision p2 physics doesnt work

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to get the collision to work in Phaser.
I'm using the p2 physics and I want a function to get called, when the player hits a door:

```
    //Load player                        
    playerSprite = this.game.add.sprite(50, 900, 'player-front');
    player = new Player(playerSprite);

    //1
    //Enter door 
    door = this.game.add.sprite(350, 865, 'player-back');
```

Then i start the physics:

```
 this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    //Setting up witch tiles needs colliders
    map.setCollision(261, true, 'Collisions');
    this.game.physics.p2.convertTilemap(map, 'Collisions');
    this.game.physics.p2.enable([player.sprite, door], false);
    player.sprite.body.fixedRotation = true;

    //Physics engine create collision bodies from the tiles

    this.game.physics.arcade.enable(map);
    this.game.physics.setBoundsToWorld();
    //
    this.game.physics.p2.setImpactEvents(true);

    this.game.physics.p2.updateBoundsCollisionGroup();
```

Then I make 2 variables and set on the collsision to the player

```
    var playerCollisionGroup = this.game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
    var doorCollisionGroup = this.game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();

    door.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.P2JS;

    door.body.setCollisionGroup(doorCollisionGroup);

    door.body.collides(playerCollisionGroup);

    player.sprite.body.setCollisionGroup(playerCollisionGroup);

    player.sprite.body.collides(doorCollisionGroup, this.hitDoor, this);
```

And the hitDoor function looks like this:

```
 hitDoor: function(body1, body2){
    console.log("Collision works");
},
```

I dont know why it's now working.
Someone that can see the problem?
Ty

Comment: Was this supposed to be an edit to [your question from last month](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36812743/11912)?

Comment: I dont know if it's an edit, but yea it's almost the same problem except that i found out of something new

Comment: And im sry if i should have done it another way

Comment: I *think* making an edit to your first question would have been best, given that there was just the one answer and it seemingly wasn't helping. I did just notice that you have `this.game.physics.arcade.enable(map);` and I don't believe you can have a mix of Physics systems in Phaser.

Comment: Okay, ty for telling me! Yea I can also see that now, but still nothing happens when i out comment it or changing it to p2 instead of arcade.. @JamesSkemp

Comment: I don't have much experience with P2, but .. if no one else has posted an answer by the time I'm off work in about 7 hours I'll come back and take a look.

Comment: I hope someone will make an answer! But Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Did u look at it @JamesSkemp

Comment: I gave it a cursory look, yes, but I didn't see anything obvious and ran out of time to customize my working example to match the code you provided.

Comment: Ahh okay. I've tried to look at it again, but I still can't get it to work.. @JamesSkemp